# SQL: extract keys and values of a jsonb field as rows of two separate columns

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

In my postgresql DB I have the following query

```
select json_field from my_table where role='addresses_line';
```

returning

```
{"alpha": ["10001"], "beta": ["10002"], "gamma": ["10003"]}
```

where `json_field` is of type JSONB.

I am looking for a way to query all the keys and all the values from this json field,
so that the output would be

```
  key  |  value
----------------
alpha  |  10001
beta   |  10002
gamma  |  10003
```

Is there a way to do it ?

---

### generalizing the question after it got the solution answer

When I wrote the question I did not paid attention, so I implicitly asked not only to extract keys and values of a jsonb field as rows of two separate columns, but also - assuming that all the values associated to the key were 1 element-long arrays - to select only the value of the first element of the list in the value associated to each key.
The solution given by stefanov.fm does so.

Now, to generalize the answer, in case the first query result were

```
{"alpha": 10001, "beta": 10002, "gamma": 10003}
```

then the desired second query is

```
select key, value
from jsonb_each
(
  (select json_field from my_table where role='addresses_line')
);
```

thanks to @stefanov.fm

Comment: What if the array for `alpha` contains 100 elements instead of just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jsonb_each` function.

```sql
select key, (value ->> 0) as value
from jsonb_each
(
  (select json_field from my_table where role='addresses_line')
);
```

Here is an illustration with your data as a literal.

```sql
select key, (value ->> 0) as value 
from jsonb_each('{"alpha": ["10001"], "beta": ["10002"], "gamma": [10003"]}');
```

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| beta | 10002 |
| alpha | 10001 |
| gamma | 10003 |